# SSRS get background color codes from database - expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

How can I make use below SSRS expression functionality to get background colors from database, as tooltip explains ?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking "How to set the background color of a label to a value stored in the database"?

Comment: To clarify, that tooltip in the image is referring to properties set in a multidimensional SSAS model. But, as the answer below suggests you can get colors from a database and use them in the properties to set the background color.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the background color value from the database consider the below example 
 For the text box
1. go to the textbox properties --> fill
2. select expression for the fill color option as shown in below screenshot

[image: screenshot]

3. in expression give the field value from the dataset
   eg: `=Fields!color.Value`

for that text box the color will applied .